# How to add a lookup when creating a new ListItem?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I've found multiple Q/As here and other resources about adding a lookup value to a new `ListItem` upon creation and, based on those examples, it seems like it should be straight forward. However, I cannot find the proper way to do it. I get different exceptions depending on what I'm trying but the most common approach throws a `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException`. If I remove the lookups, I can add a new `ListItem`.

> Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only.

Here's what I have:

```
var web = context.Web;
var camlQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
var webList = web.GetListByTitle(title);
var items = webList.GetItems(camlQuery);
context.Load(items);
context.ExecuteQuery();

// To test, I duplicate the first ListItem
var first = items.First();
var creationInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
var dup = webList.AddItem(creationInfo);

foreach (var (k, v) in first.FieldValues)
{
    if (!importantFields.Contains(k)) continue;
    // IsLookup determines if it's a lookup and returns a different variation.
    // Not used in this example as it didn't work either.
    if (IsLookup(k, out var key))
    {
        var lookup = new FieldLookupValue();
        var existingLookup = v as FieldLookupValue; 
        lookup.LookupId = existingLookup!.LookupId;
        dup[k] = lookup;
    } else dup[k] = v;
    Console.WriteLine(k);
}
dup.Update();
webList.Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

How to add a lookup when creating a new ListItem?